# A Box Packing problem with multiple boxes

Tags: python, algorithm

You are given N boxes and M objects. Each box has a capacity n(i), stored in a list. Each object has a volume m(i), stored in a list. Design a packing solution that packs as many items as possible. Moreover, if there are multiple solutions, waste as little space as possible.Return a list where l(i) stores the corresponding box to be packed inside. If object i cannot be packed, set l(i) as -1.

I tried to loop Knapsack for N times to solve the problem. I assign value 1 to each object to put as many items as possible into each box. However, I am still confused about how to satisfy the second condition "waste as little space as possible".

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to post the code you came up with so far to receive answers that support your coding. Concerning the space constraint, let me rephrase it: _"Try to minimize the overall sum of space that is left over in boxes (i.e. not used for storing an object)"_

Comment: Stackoverflow is probably not the best place for this question. This sounds more like a math problem trying to be solved with code, and not a coding problem in and of itself. 

You would probably have better luck if you provided code showing what you have tried so far, and welcome to SO!

Comment: [Not an easy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem#Hardness_of_bin_packing)